# Using text/x-kendo-template with Nested JSON

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

I have the following JSON structure returned from the web service call:

```
[
    {"Site_Metadata":
        [   
            {"Site":"Brady","Type_ID":1,"Locations":"Brady","Reads_Per_Day":2,"SR_Sites":"Brady"},
            {"Site":"Desert Peak 2","Type_ID":1,"Locations":"Desert Peak 2","Reads_Per_Day":2,"SR_Sites":"Desert Peak 2"}
        ]
    }
]
```

And I use the following code to display the “Site”:

```
<div id="View" data-role="view" data-init="Sites">
        <ul id="Sites"></ul>
</div>
<script>
        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
        function Sites()
        {
            var WebAPIDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport:{
                    read:{
                        url:"http://...",
                        dataType:"JSON"
                    }
                }

            });
            $("#Sites").kendoMobileListView({dataSource:WebAPIDataSource, template : $("#sites-template").html() });


        }
</script>


<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="sites-template">
        #: Site #
</script>
```

It doesn’t work! Only if I remove the “Site_Metadata” level will it populate the list for me.

Comment: please make sample for your case in [telerik dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I had to add the schema name in the DataSource definition.
Here's what I did:

```
<body>

    <div id="View" data-role="view" data-init="Sites">
        <ul id="Sites"></ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
        function Sites()
        {
            var WebAPIDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport:{
                    read:{
                        url:"http://...",
                        dataType:"JSON"
                    }
                },
                schema:{
                    data:"Site_Metadata"
                }

            });

            $("#Sites").kendoMobileListView({dataSource:WebAPIDataSource, template : $("#sites-template").html() });


        }
    </script>


   <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="sites-template">
        #:Site#
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your web service return object is an array, not JSON.
So set your list-view  dataSource as : `WebAPIDataSource[0].Site_Metadata`

```
 $("#Sites").kendoMobileListView({
              dataSource:WebAPIDataSource[0].Site_Metadata, 
              template : $("#sites-template").html()
   });
```